# Cannot convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<System.Data.Linq.Binary> to byte

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to select an `image` column from my database via linq and save it into `q3`

```
-------------------------------
|         table : admin       |
-------------------------------
| username | password | image |
-------------------------------
```

Query:

```
var q3 = alnq.tbl_Admins.Where(c => c.fld_UserName == userName).Select(c => c.fld_Image);
```

When I want to convert this query to an array of bytes, I get an error:

```
byte [] DbImageByte = q3.ToArray();
```

Error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Data.Linq.Binary[]' to 'byte[]'

Comment: What type is `fld_Image` ??

Comment: it is varbinary(Max)

Comment: Can you please try to add .FirstOrDefault() after .select()? and then check

Comment: So when you do `.Select(c => c.fld_Image)` you are saying put all of the `varbinary(Max)` into an array. Which means you'll have resulting data type of `IEnumerable<byte[]>`

Comment: Like the the other answer suggests, you need to do something like `.Select(c => c.fld_Image.ToArray())`

Comment: Ankiktumur ..it works.thanks

Comment: I gave description in the answer please mark it as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Linq

whenever we write select with where condition whether its our primary key it will not understand that can have only one row to return.
so we need to tell the query please return only one row with `FirstOrDefault()` method of Linq.

so for your case just at `FirstOrDefault()` after your query so it will result only one row instead of set of rows.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, `.Select(c => c.fld_Image)` **gives you a collection** with one item(or more if `fld_UserName` isn't unique). You have to just take that first item out of the list by using `FirstOrDefault()`.

Use this:

```
var q3 = alnq.tbl_Admins.Where(c => c.fld_UserName == userName).Select(c => c.fld_Image).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: @GiladGreen Yes, the cast error is there because of `Binary[]` to `byte[]`. After taking First Element, it would become `Binary` to `byte[]`, which should be a valid cast.

Answer (score 0):

Every Ling.binary contain byte array you have to store it in a array or list

```
Binary[] binary = q3.ToArray();
List<byte[]> byteArray = new List<byte[]>();
foreach(var b in binary){
   byteArray.Add(b.ToArray());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I thought the q3 is a IEnumarble list.

Could you please try something like

```
   var q3 = alnq.tbl_Admins.Where(c => c.fld_UserName == userName).Select(c => c.fld_Image).FirstOrDefault();
byte[] DbImageByte = q3.ToArray();
```